# Android Log shows "W/OpenGLRenderer: Area is 0 while computing centroid"

Tags: android, opengl-es

In a lot of my screens the log gets spammed with the warning

```
W/OpenGLRenderer: Area is 0 while computing centroid!
```

I already saw that this is related to movement in my screens, e.g. when I scroll a recyclerView. Or when a self-made progress bar is shown. Any idea how to fix it without disabling hardware acceleration?

Comment: A quick search on the Web [shows](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/libs/hwui/ShadowTessellator.cpp) that the warning is fired when trying to get the `centroid` of a polygon whose area is zero.

Comment: @Ripi2 nothing I'm doing anywhere. Believe me, I used google already.